# Metallic sparkle effect in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, android, graphics, opengl-es

I'm working on an Android and iPhone app. I'm rendering lots of smallish (about 32 pixels) billboards to the screen for a particle system and want to give a glitter-like sparkle to each billboard e.g. as the particles are falling, random ones will briefly light up and sparkle as they catch the light. Is there a simple way to achieve this effect? As a limitation, I cannot use pixel/vertex shaders.

I was thinking something along the lines of a giving each billboard metal-like lighting effect (although I'm not sure how to do this part) coupled with giving each billboard a random and constantly rotating normal with flat shading so that each billboard would randomly light up. I'm having trouble making it look nice.

Comment: This kinda comes across as a "Teach me OpenGL" question.  There isn't some simple solution someone can give you, without actually coding it for you.

Comment: I think that's unfair; I'm not asking anyone to teach me OpenGL and I haven't asked for code. I'm asking for some high-level hints at what techniques I can use to simulate this effect given the limitation of no pixel/vertex shaders (which are involved in every tutorial I'm finding). Something high-level like "use a texture like this...set the lightning like this" would be fine. I'm not expecting an exact solution, just some pointers for what I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know OpenGL, and I did't actually try anything I write below.

You can have another, 'brightly lit', texture and substitute it when normal is nearly at the 'shine' position.

Take a piece of metal and rotate it. Once the normal is close to 'full shine' position, the metal shines a bit brighter, and a muted reflex travels through it, with a bright flash in the middle, then it is dull again.

If you can, apply a second bright texture of a narrow 'reflex' band and move it through surface of the billboards that are in a near-shine position, shifting them accordingly to normal angle. When the normal is at the shine position (± epsilon), apply the 'full shine' texture.

Also, unless your plates fly in vacuum, there will be a halo due to atmosphere. Add a rectangle say 50% bigger than the plate right behind it, and apply to it a semi-transparent halo texture that becomes fully transparent closer to edges. You only need it at the fill shine moment.